# How can I populate h:selectItems from *.properties files dynamically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, richfaces, facelets

If I have this peace of code:

```
<rich:select enableManualInput="true" defaultLabel="Select time spent">

       <f:selectItems value="" />

</rich:select>
```

and a properties file like:

```
key1=val1
key2=val2
key3=val3
key4=val4
```

The question is how to take all the values from the properties file and make a `ArrayList<SelectItems>` from them for example so I can use them in the drop-down list?

Comment: A structure of key1=val1, key2=val2, key3=val3, key4=val4 in the properties file would be much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the layout of your properties file i would suggest storing it like

```
key1=val1
key2=val2
key3=val3
key4=val4
```

Properties Tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

Api: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html.

```
public ArrayList<SelectItem> propertiesToSelectItemList(final Properties props)
    {
        final ArrayList<SelectItem> result = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> me : props.entrySet())
        {
            result.add(new SelectItem((String)me.getKey(), (String)me.getValue()));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Unfortunately Properties is backed by a Hashtable<Object,Object>. But unless you mess with it, the casts should be safe.

Comment: This is nice but how can I get the values from the properties file to pass them to this method?

Comment: Read the links on Properties that i posted above.